# WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext sharedAudioPresentationContext]_block_invoke Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube

Hi I am trying to play the videos in collection view cells by using: [Link](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player)

When I am run my application video play successfully.
After completing of video again again we are pressing on start button it is crashed.and show the following errors.

```
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

> WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext
>   sharedAudioPresentationContext]_block_invoke

I write the following code.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            if collectionView == self.video_collectionview
            { 
                // For videoCollectionView
                let videocell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)as! VideoCollectionViewCell
                 videocell.videotitle.text = videotitle[indexPath.row]
                videocell.videotime.text = videotime[indexPath.row]
                let myVideoURL = videourls[indexPath.row]
                videocell.videoview.loadVideoURL(myVideoURL as URL)
               // videocell.videoview.layer.cornerRadius = 15

                return videocell
            }
        }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == video_collectionview
         {  
            let videocell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)as! VideoCollectionViewCell
            let myVideoURL = videourls[indexPath.row]
            videocell.videoview.loadVideoURL(myVideoURL as URL)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to install XCDYouTubeKit pod file.

In did select row method call this function with videoid parameter.

```
func playVideo(videoid:String) {

        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoid) { (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
            if let streamURL = video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue] {
                playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
                playerViewController.player?.play()
            } else {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```